# Is it possible to install missing libraries on heroku.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app that has a dependency on uuid.h.  During the `bundle install` portion of the `git push heroku master` I get (what seems to be the key part of the backtrace):

```
   checking for uuid/uuid.h... no
   checking for uuid.h... no
   configure: error: Neither uuid/uuid.h nor uuid.h found - required for brass, chert and flint (you may need to install the uuid-dev, libuuid-devel or e2fsprogs-devel package)
```

Is there any way to get any of those libraries installed on the server?  I'm guessing not by my own power, but just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the cedar stack, you can vendor in anything you want. It may not always be easy, but you'll be able to do it. Check out https://github.com/heroku/vulcan and projects on the heroku github account that have the word buildpack for inspiration.